# Webpage couldn't be loaded with System.Net.WebResponse

Tags: c#, http

I use the next code to load webpage content:

```
    private string HttpGet(string uri)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        try
        { 
            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), false);
            return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "HttpGet: Response error",
               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In most cases I actually get html content. It works good with http;//stackoverflow.com, but if you try to load http;//www.icetrade.by (I know about semicolon, just don't want them to be a link), which works normally in web browser even without javascript enabled, you will get something like this:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in <b>K:\hosting\icetrade.by\html\includes\module.class.php</b> on line <b>141</b><br />
```

What is the reason of such behavior and how can I get the real html content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a server-side error. Probably this site cannot handle situation when some headers, like UserAgent or Cookies are absent.

If this is the site that you control, then check what happens on line 141 in module.class.php